# Add a custom keyboard layout to the OS language in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke, culture

In Windows 10, you can go to `Language preferences`, select a langue (English US for example) and click Options, then add a keyboard.

Is there a way to do this programatically in C# ?

all i was able to achieve is Load a language with a predefined keyboard layout using `LoadKeyboardLayout`, following the codes in : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings

For example how to add this:

0409:0000040C

English with French keyboard ?
 (knowing that it's easily done through the windows settings interface)